# problem adding tag to already existing tag using javascript (ES6)

Tags: javascript

well I was trying to to add 100 div tag(with different content) to an already existing tag using nested loop. loops look perfectly working (I have tested it already). but there is problem in adding created dives in fact none of them show up in the output.

javascript

```
 let result ;
   for(let i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++){
       for(let j =1 ; j <= 10 ; j++){
           result = i * j;
           document.getElementById("wrap").write("<div class='box'>"+result+"</div>");
       }
   }
```

html

```
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

I think problem comes from **.getByID** or **.write**
I will be happy to see your opinion and thanks for helping

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("wrap").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", "<div class='box'>"+result+"</div>")` or `crrateElement`, `append`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `html` content of a DOM element can be done by using `innerHTML` and not with `write` method. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```
document.getElementById("wrap").innerHTML = "<div class='box'>"+result+"</div>";
```

There is no `write` method exist for dom elements. If you run your code in browser, you can see an error in console as below

[image]

The above error states that there is no write method available for DOM elements.

So what you have to do is to append the `innerHTML` of your element with id `wrap` with `"<div class='box'>"+result+"</div>"`. To keep on appending the new template with the existing you can use the below statement inside the loop.

```
document.getElementById("wrap").innerHTML += "<div class='box'>"+result+"</div>";
```

But accessing `dom` elements directly is a little costly in terms of performace. In your case you need to update the content of `dom` 100 times, which means that you have to access the `dom` 100 times in a loop.

The best approach will be creating the template string inside the loop and setting the `innerHTML` once the loop finishes its execution. This will make dom update only once, rather than 100 times. This provides better performance aswell.

**Working fiddle**

```js
let result;
let template = '';
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    result = i * j;
    template += "<div class='box'>" + result + "</div>";
  }
}
document.getElementById("wrap").innerHTML = template;
```

```html
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements do not have a `.write` method.

```js
document.querySelector('div').write('bar');
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
```

Add to the `innerHTML` of the `wrap`

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    const result = i * j;
    document.getElementById("wrap").innerHTML += "<div class='box'>" + result + "</div>";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

or create an element with `document.createElement` and change its contents.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    const result = i * j;
    const div = document.getElementById("wrap").appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    div.className = 'box';
    div.textContent = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap"></div>
```